# Why do git hotfix branches often use the version number?

Tags: git

This has confused me for a while, but in certain projects, and tutorials on good git conventions, feature branches use specific naming, e.g. '`feat/number_counter`' while hotfixes use version numbers '`hotfix/0.1.1`'.

Naming hot fixes by version numbers seems to have quite a few drawbacks IMO as

1. it is not apparent what the branch fixes prior to a merge (assuming the merge message clarifies the purpose) and
2. other branches may invalidate the 0.1.1 name, such as if someone else branches and merges their 0.1.2 hotfix, or a feature bumps the version number to 0.2.0.

So with my understanding of caveats in mind, why is this convention so popular, in contrast to, for example, '`hotfix/counter_overflow`'?

Comment: I have never seen or heard of this convention. Where exactly are you seeing this? It does not seem like a good convention at all.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. it is not apparent what the branch fixes prior to a merge (assuming the merge message clarifies purpose)

One possible justification for this naming convention is the the 0.1.1 refers to a git tag, not a branch. Since a tag is immutable (should bot be moved), you know exactly from which commit the hotfix branch started from.

> 2. other branches may invalidate the 0.1.1 name, such as if someone else branches and merges their 0.1.2 hotfix, or a feature bumps version number to 0.2.0

Again, since the tag does not move, that hotfix branch starting point is clearly identified and said branch can be merged to others which might need it.